# Can I use tee to display output that other utilities tend to suppress?

Tags: bash, tee

The macos `pbcopy` utility grabs its input stream and stores it in the system clipboard, without displaying anything. So, when I want to copy/paste the output of a command in the terminal, I typically first run a command to print normally to see what I'm getting then run again to pipe to pbcopy.

Similar utilities exist on Linux, IIRC. Can `tee` be used to send data to pbcopy, rather than a file, thus allowing a display at the same as the copy?

Example:

For whatever reason, I want to document something about files in a directory, but only list files with `a` or `b` characters in their name.

The first `ls` is used to make sure I've filtered out what I don't want.  The second is used to put the results in my clipboard.  Can I do everything in one step, by somehow leveraging `tee`?

```
% touch a b c
% ls | egrep 'a|b'
a
b
% ls | egrep 'a|b' | pbcopy
%
```

###### clipboard content, after the 2nd run, which I would prefer in one step:

```
a
b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be doable. Either have `tee` print directly to the terminal with `/dev/tty`, or use process substitution (in Bash/ksh/zsh) to have it print to `pbcopy`:

```
whatever | tee /dev/tty | pbcopy
```

or

```
whatever | tee >(pbcopy)
```

(The process substitution builds a pipeline to `pbcopy` similarly to a regular pipeline, but makes it available as a filename instead.)